# How to configure the javafx plugin in a custom gradle plugin?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, javafx, gradle-plugin

I am new to gradle. I am working on a kotlin library that requires JavaFX. I wanted to use gradle to manage my dependencies and make it easier to include my library in a new project.

My library project applies and configures the javafx plugin and its build file looks like this (kotlin dsl):

```kt
plugins {
    `java-library`
    id("org.openjfx.javafxplugin")
}

group = "me.shai"
version = "1.0"

javafx {
    version = "15.0.1"
    modules = listOf("javafx.controls", "javafx.fxml")
}

dependencies {
    // Other dependencies

    testImplementation(kotlin("test-junit5"))
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.0")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.6.0")
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

kotlin {
    explicitApi()
}
```

Apparently, a project that wants to use my library also has to apply and configure JavaFX. Here's an example for a build file of a demo project that consumes my library:

```kt
plugins {
    id("org.openjfx.javafxplugin")
}

group = "me.shai"
version = "1.0"

javafx {
    version = "15.0.1"
    modules = listOf("javafx.controls", "javafx.fxml")
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":MyLib")) // Pretend the library is published so we use a url instead of local project
}
```

This is slightly annoying, so I decided to do something similar to JavaFX: write a custom plugin to include my project. The plugin needs to:

1. Add my library as a dependency
2. Apply the JavaFX plugin
3. Configure the JavaFX plugin

I managed to achieve steps 1 and 2, but I am stuck at step 3. How can I configure the JavaFX plugin from a custom plugin kotlin class?

Here's what I have so far:

```kt
package mylib.gradle

import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.api.artifacts.DependencyResolutionListener
import org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolvableDependencies
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.project

class MyLibPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        // Apply the javafx plugin
        project.plugins.apply("org.openjfx.javafxplugin")
        // How to configure javafx here?

        val implementationDeps = project.configurations.getByName("implementation").dependencies
        project.gradle.addListener(object : DependencyResolutionListener {
            override fun beforeResolve(dependencies: ResolvableDependencies) {
                // Add dependency on my library project.
                implementationDeps.add(project.dependencies.project(":MyLib"))
                project.gradle.removeListener(this)
            }

            override fun afterResolve(dependencies: ResolvableDependencies) {}
        })
    }
}
```

I am basically trying to write the equivalent of the build script block:

```kt
javafx {
    version = "15.0.1"
    modules = listOf("javafx.controls", "javafx.fxml")
}
```

And I can't figure out how to achieve this. I'd appreciate any help on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

You would configure the `javafx` extension just as you would in the build file:

```
// build.gradle[.kts]
dependencies {
    implementation("org.openjfx:javafx-plugin:0.0.10")
}
```

And the plugin implementation:

```
import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPlugin
import org.openjfx.gradle.JavaFXOptions

open class MyLibPlugin : Plugin<Project> {

    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        project.pluginManager.apply("org.openjfx.javafxplugin")

        val myLibDependency = project.dependencies.project(mapOf("path" to ":MyLib"))
        project.dependencies.add(JavaPlugin.IMPLEMENTATION_CONFIGURATION_NAME, myLibDependency)

        project.extensions.configure(JavaFXOptions::class.java) {
            it.version = "15.0.1"
            it.modules = listOf("javafx.controls", "javafx.fxml")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried this, but I get an error `Unresolved reference: openjfx` in the import statement. Maybe I am missing something in the plugin build file?

Comment: Ensure you have the correct dependency; see revised edit.

Comment: Still not working. Now I get `Could not find org.openjfx:javafx-plugin:0.0.10` in the build file. Is it possible that it is defined in a different repository or something?

Comment: @ShaiAvr Are you sure you have `repositories { gradlePluginPortal() }` block in the build file?